# How to check if a day is valid within a date

Tags: java

I am writing a program for a class that checks to make sure a date entered by a user is valid. I have figured out how to write everything up to the day. The program has to check if the entered day is a valid day including the variation in days between months and leap years. Any input would be appreciated, Thank you! P.s. We can only use the standard library within Java to accomplish this.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    String date;

    System.out.println("Enter a date (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
    date = kbd.nextLine();


    if (date.length() < 10){
        System.out.println("Too few characters in the date");

    }else if(date.length() < 10){
        System.out.println("Too many characters in the date");
    }else{
        if (Character.toString(date.charAt(2)).equals("/") && Character.toString(date.charAt(5)).equals("/")){
            if (Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0,2)) >= 1 && Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0,2)) <= 12){
                int day = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(3,6));
                if(day < 1){

                    System.out.println("Day is not valid");

                }else{


                }


            }else{
                System.out.println("Month is not valid");
            }

        }else{
            System.out.println("Incorrect format");
        }
    }


    kbd.close();
}
```

}

Comment: you should parse whole date, not in parts

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: @Mureinik checking to see if the entered day is a valid day

Comment: `> 10` for too many. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the DateFormat class (and the derived classes such as SimpleDateFormat). It has a parse method which does it for you.

```
String strDate = "29/02/2017";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
df.setLenient(false); 
Date date = df.parse(strDate);
if (date != null) {
    // Input is valid
} else {
    // Input not valid
}
```

Comment: This very snippet returns valid for me: https://repl.it/repls/HandyPunyWamp
It works as expected if you add "df.setLenient(false);". Please edit your answer.

Comment: @AlgorithmandBlues, thank you. I edited the answer. In case `df.setLenient(flase)` is not inserted, the string "29/02/2017" (and similar ones) return a date referring to March 1st.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what your question is... but I pasted your code in Eclipse IDE, (it didn't work), then I changed some stuff, (now it works). Take a look at it and see what you think. I'm not as experienced as most, but I'd be happy to help more if you'd like, (like if you wanted to verify more than just the day/etc).

### An example for input (for this code) is      10,23,1997

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    String date;

    System.out.println("Enter a date (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
    date = kbd.nextLine();

    if (date.length() < 10){ System.out.println("Too few characters in the date"); }

    else if(date.length() < 10){ System.out.println("Too many characters in the date");}

    else
    {
        if (Character.toString(date.charAt(2)).equals("/") && Character.toString(date.charAt(5)).equals("/"))
        {

            if (Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0,1)) >= 1 && Integer.parseInt(date.substring(3,4)) <= 12)
            {
                int day = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(3,4));
                if(day < 1){ System.out.println("Day is not valid"); }
                else{ System.out.println("User inputed Date : "+ date + " is valid."); }
            }

            else{ System.out.println("Month is not valid");  }

        }else{ System.out.println("Incorrect format"); }
    }


    kbd.close();
}
}
```